# How Add New Button to Gutenberg Editing Toolbar

Tags: block-editor

When i publishing a content using Gutenberg I miss a button to create a new post right there without leaving the editor and going back to this.

See the image to better illustrate the issue.

[image: Gutenberg Add New]

How can I create this button?

I thank you all for your help.